# How can i check if model field was changed in post_save?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have to do some extra logic in post_save if one of model fields was updated, but can't check if it was updated.

Tried to override init method like this

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Profile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.__old_city = self.city
```

and in post_save check

```
if instance.city != instance.__old_city:
    #extra logic
```

but got an exception

> AttributeError: 'Profile' object has no attribute '__old_city'

What i'm doing wrong(except of using signals :D )?

Comment: An attribute with a double-underscore is name-mangled so it is not directly accessible from outside the class. Solution is not to use a double underscore but a single one (or none at all).

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you!
I tried to do with a single underscore, but pycharm gave a warning  "Access to a protected member _folder of a class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your using name mangling.

Double Underscore (Name Mangling)

From the Python docs:

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, so it can be used to
>   define class-private instance and class variables, methods, variables
>   stored in globals, and even variables stored in instances. private to
>   this class on instances of other classes.

Which means to access `instance.__old_city` you need to use `_className__attribute_name`

So `__old_city` will be mangled `->` `_Profile__old_city`